# Ask latest version Redis on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: redis

What is the latest version of Redis installed on Ubuntu 18.04? I have consulted many sources, but the highest version is Version: 5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.2 .My project needs to upgrade to a higher version ,hope everyone has an answer